# Html convert in jQuery

Tags: jquery, mobile

i have a question about converting HTML in jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/nMR85/1118/

How can i write this HTML code in jQuery?:

```
$('#deneme').append(
    ul 
    data-role="listview" 
    data-split-icon="gear" 
    data-split-theme="d" 
    data-inset="true")...
```

**this is not same code:**

```
$('#deneme').append('
    <ul data-role="listview" 
        data-split-icon="gear" 
        data-split-theme="d" 
        data-inset="true">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="../../_assets/img/album-bb.jpg">
                <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
                <p>Broken Bells</p>
            </a>
            <a href="#purchase" 
                data-rel="popup" 
                data-position-to="window" 
                data-transition="pop">
                Purchase album
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
');
</br>
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="../../_assets/img/album-bb.jpg">                      
            <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
            <p>Broken Bells</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#purchase" 
            data-rel="popup" 
            data-position-to="window" 
            data-transition="pop">
            Purchase album
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

it should look like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" 
    data-split-icon="gear" 
    data-split-theme="d" 
    data-inset="true" 
    class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
```

but that shows me:

```
<ul data-role="listview" 
    data-split-icon="gear" 
    data-split-theme="d" 
    data-inset="true">
```

that shows me without class.

Comment: Except for putting it in quotes, you have. What are you wondering about?

Answer (score 0):

You can append the `ul` by doing the following.

```
$('#deneme').append('<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true" />').trigger('create');
```

Comment: "class" will not be added automatically

Comment: @aldimeola1122 I added the `class` attribute. Not sure why you couldn't just type it.

Comment: because if write this than it is too long

Comment: @aldimeola1122 I've edited my answer to user `.trigger('create')` which will tell jquery ui to apply styles and such to the `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to add it using Vanilla:

```
$('#deneme')[0].innerHTML = '<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true">...'
```

or if you want jQuery:

```
$('#deneme').html('<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true">...')
```

Comment: sorry, but I still can't see difference... but if you need to add html code into `$('#deneme')` you can do it this way: `$('#deneme')[0].innerHTML += '<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear"...'` Or I miss something?

Comment: you should check that you really add class... in your example in `jsfiddle` and your previous code I can't see any classes

Comment: In this example I added `ul` with `class` into the `<div id="deneme"></div>` and class was added successfully:
http://jsfiddle.net/3xyq3/